# UNIX Matlab - Calculate plot in loop, but show at the end

Tags: matlab, plot, hide, figure

I am plotting stem plots in given figures within a function using the following code...

```
% plot - phase = 1,2 or 3, with different data each time
% Each phase is called more than once
figure(phase);
stem(1:length(phaseSystem),phaseFailureTimes);hold on
```

This function is called several times within a loop, plotting on the same figures iteratively. 
I want each plot to be calculated but not shown until a later time. This is because the figures currently show and update live, which is slowing down the script. I'd rather calculate but hide them, as opposed to storing all the data and plotting them at the end.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a bit of reorganizing so that your function outputs the 3 values for your variables `phaseSystem` and `phaseFailureTimes` as n by 3 matrices.

Let me call this function `calculate_phase_failure`. Then the script/function that calls `calculate_phase_failure` could accumulate the results. Finally, a separate loop at the end could generate your plots. If the number of elements are different for each iteration of your loops you might need to use a cell-array to accumulate your results.

Here is an example for the simplest case where the number of elements is consistent between iteration of your loops.

```
for i=1:n
     [phaseSystem(:,:,i), phaseFailureTime(:,:,i)] = calculate_phase_failure( <input variables> ); 
end

% now generate your plot
for i=1:n
     for phase=1:size(phaseFailureTime,2)
           figure(phase);
           stem(1:size(phaseSystem,1), phaseFailureTime(:,phase,i))
     end
end
```